# How to change wallpaper like Mojave in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mac, desktop-background

I have two images - Mojave Day and Mojave Night.
So I want to set them by time.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way, and a hard way.

### Easy Way

Install an application called [Variety](https://launchpad.net/variety).  That allows you to change the wallpaper at specific intervals.  So if you want the Night wallpaper to run from 1900 to 0700, you can do that.

Of course, depending on where you are in the world, the length of nights and days may vary during the year.

### Hard Way

I'll sketch out how this works, if you're interested.

- Write a small [Python program to determine sunrise and sunset for your location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986527/sunrise-and-sunset-time-in-python).
- Every 30 minutes, run a cron job to run that program.
- If it is past sunset, change the photo to night.
- If it is after sunrise, change the photo to day.

Comment: I struggled with Variety for awhile but there were just too many glitches so had to abandon it. This was a year ago though so maybe they've been worked out. Have you been using Variety with success?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME has a dynamic wallpaper by default, and it's using only an .xml file to swap the photos. I suggest you just look at how it looks and write your own, it's not that hard. And you can have much more than 2 images.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/create-custom-transitioning-background-your-gnome-228-desktop